# Implementation of Super() method in Multiple Inheritance Python Code Problem statement is:-

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, superclass

I am trying to Implement a child class called `mathnew` and parent classes as `sqroot`, `addition`, `subtraction`, `multiplication` and `division`. Use the `super()` function to inherit the parent methods.

This is the code.

```
from math import *
from functools import reduce

class sqroot:

    def __init__(self,n1):
        self.n1 = n1

    def sqroot(self):
        return(sqrt(self.n1))

class addition:

    def __init__(self,n2):
        self.n = n2

    def add(self):
        return(sum(self.n))


class subtraction:

    def __init__(self,n3,n4):
        self.n1 = n3
        self.n2 = n4

    def sub(self):
        return((self.n1-self.n2))

class multiplication:

    def __init__(self,n5):
        self.n = n5

    def product(self):
        return((reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, self.n)))

class division:

    def __init__(self,n6,n7):
        self.n1 = n6
        self.n2 = n7

    def div(self):
        return("The quotient is :- {}".format(self.n1/self.n2))


class mathnew(sqroot,addition,subtraction,multiplication,division):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


d1 = mathnew(4)
print(d1.sqroot(4))
```

I tried multiple ways but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import math


class sqroot:
    def sqroot(self,a):
        print(math.sqrt(a))


class addition:
    def add(self,a,b):
        print(a+b)


class subtraction:
    def sub(self,a,b):
        print(a-b)


class multiplication:
    def mult(self,a,b):
        print(a*b)


class division:
    def div(self,a,b):
        print(a/b)


class mathnew(sqroot, addition, subtraction, multiplication, division):
    def __init__(self):
        super()


m = mathnew()

m.sqroot(4)
m.add(4,5)
m.sub(5,8)
m.mult(5,6)
m.div(47,2)
```